# How do I integrate Identity without EF in an app that uses ADO.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-identity

I am trying to add membership system using Identity to my ASP.NET Core app. The problem is that Identity uses Entity Framework by default and I am not using it in my app. How do I add Identity without EF ? Is it even possible to use EF just for Identity and integrate it with my existing database ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you cloud find a ready to use NuGet package for your problem. If not you can always write up your own implementation of IUserStore and pass it as a parameter to UserManager instance on creation. This will let you use all of the Identity perks with your own user store (handled by ADO.NET in your case).